# How to call a function in screen manager kivy? [ closed ]

Tags: python, function, kivy

I am trying to do sth with the screen manager in Kivy but i get confused on how to use it : (

i want to call function `Update()` using Clock.schedule_interval , but when i press the button on top left it shows error  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'` i think it s because of the `main` return : ( so want to ask how to call a function and return it while using the screen manager : ) thx

.py

```
kivy.lang.Builder.load_string(
"""
#:kivy 2.0.0

<SettingScreen>:

    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'main'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        
        
<MainScreen>:

    background_color: 0, 0, 0
    
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id: go_setting_button
            size_hint: .15, .15
            background_color: root.background_color
            center_y: root.height - self.size[1] /4
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'setting'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.size[0] /4, self.pos[1]
                    size: self.size[0] /2, self.size[0] /2
                    source: 'setting.jpg'

        Label:
            id: center_label
            text: "Hello World !"
            font_size: 25
            center: root.center
            markup: True
""")

# class SettingScreen ##############################################################################
class SettingScreen(Screen):

    pass


# class MainScreen #################################################################################
class MainScreen(Screen):
    
    def Update(self, dt):
        
        self.ids.center_label.text = "ASDFASDFASD"
        self.ids.center_label.center = self.center
        
####################################################################################################
class MyFirstApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "My First Kivy App"

        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(SettingScreen(name = 'setting'))

        main = MainScreen()
        Clock.schedule_interval(main.Update, 1.0/60.0) #
        
        return screen_manager and main #


if __name__ == "__main__":

    MyFirstApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way your are building your app. Your code is creating two instances of `MainScreen`, only one is a part of your GUI. Here is a modified version of your `build()` method

```
def build(self):
    self.title = "My First Kivy App"

    screen_manager = ScreenManager()
    main = MainScreen(name='main')  # Only make one MainScreen
    screen_manager.add_widget(main)  # add the one MainScreen to the GUI
    # screen_manager.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
    screen_manager.add_widget(SettingScreen(name='setting'))

    # main = MainScreen()  # this creates another instance of MainScreen
    Clock.schedule_interval(main.Update, 1.0 / 60.0)  #

    return screen_manager  # can only return one widget (the root of your GUI)
```

Comment: oic ~ thanks for answering me : ) i get it now : )